# What is the meaning of the picture in the "Code of Conduct"?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

I saw this picture beside Stack Exchange's ["Code of Conduct"](/conduct).

[image: Code of Conduct image]

Please label everything and tell me the meaning of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a 3D version of the Stack Overflow logo, and I believe it's aimed to show the diversity of people who are using the Stack Exchange network. I see old and young people, devices ranging from phones/small tablets to laptops to a wall screen, both women and men, and last but not least somebody in a wheelchair, reminding me of those who rely on [accessibility functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) of Stack Exchange. The new Code of Conduct is stylized as the text in the top 'stack', probably because it's 'central' to how people should be using the network.

Comment: "*reminding me of those who rely on accessibility functions of Stack Exchange*" - and yet you didn't edit this question to include a description of the image, for those who use screen readers ;-)

Comment: You're right, I often forget those. OTOH, here it's rather clear from the context.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Code of Conduct image annotated with hand-drawn red circles and labels "Humans", "Drone", "Robot"]

If you need to know who to include, you're missing the point. I'm sure there's lot of folks we work to help outside the pictured people with beards, long hair, short hair, drones, robot arms and sneaky plants. Even dogs <sub>not pictured</sub> .

Comment: That's some fine red freehand penmanship. +1

Comment: Its about the only thing I want a touchscreen in a laptop for ;)

Comment: -1: You mis-labelled a plant. Those have feelings too. Don't exclude me ....

Comment: While I appreciate the humor behind it, I feel that it lacks sensitivity towards a non-native speaker. He asked users to label everything on the image, but who knows what he really intended by that. Google translator is often a good tool, but it is not infallible, and I feel that the user resorted to an online translator tool. And if they didn't, I'm not sure how labeling "humans" really helps.

Comment: Aah, the CoC will bite us all in the ass.

Comment: Well, that there's more about us that's similar than different. And that the specific elements are less important than the overall whole. This is less about the language barrier that well, the real intent of the COC. At the end of the day its just a pretty picture on its own.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You didn't mention : "**3D version of the Stack Overflow logo**". Your answer is not enough.